# How to handle session expiry in react e-shop app with PHP backend and Redux?

Tags: php, reactjs, session, redux, cookies

I have a problem with tracking when a login expires in React. My application is an e-shop. I have an upper bar that displays the name of the logged-in person and some custom icons exclusively for logged-in users. I have a folder with ~30 API calls to a PHP server. I am also using Redux to manage application-level state.

The issue arises because the PHP server only sends a SESSION_ID cookie, and internally, PHP checks if that session ID is associated with a certain user. If the user stops interacting, after about an hour, PHP logs out the user. However, my React application is unaware of this change. As a result, the front end displays the user menu but doesn't load any data. I want to resolve this problem.

I've come across various solutions, such as making API calls before each request or setting a timeout to periodically check the login status. However, these don't seem to be very efficient solutions.

One idea I've considered is using an Axios interceptor to handle error code 440, when the user's session expires. I could then update the Redux state to mark the app as logged out. However, there may be cases where a user fills out a form that doesn't require login, submits it, and gets a 440 error even though it's unrelated to login.

Another approach I'm thinking about is asking the backend programmer to send a cookie with each request, including an "IS_LOGGED_IN" flag with values of 1 or 0. I could then check if the logged-in status changes to 0 and update the Redux state accordingly.

Since there are many React applications, and my project seems quite standard, there should be others who have faced similar issues. Are there any better and cleaner solutions than this?